# Java painting graphics in JApplet issues

Tags: java

I hope this does not appear too much of a newbie question. I've not done graphical style programming before. My objective is to create a pinball advergame in an applet. However, I'm falling at one of the first hurdles. My applet is not displaying the results of the paintComponent method from my Table class (which extends the JPanel). I've tried several things, such as how I load the image (currently using double buffering but I did use a mediatracker before), seeing if not having any other GUI stuff would allow the painting to occur (since I wondered if it was being drawn underneath somehow) and other things. This problem has stumped me and I'm starting to wonder (and hope) if it's something small that I've overlooked, if it is, then I'm sorry but would still be grateful for help, as I can't go very far without this problem being fixed first. My code for my Pinball (applet) and Table class are below, the other classes aren't implemented yet. Once again, I appreciate any help.

```
import javax.swing.*; // useful for the drawing side, also going to be a JApplet
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Pinball extends JApplet {
    // variables go here
    Table table;

    // further initialisation of the GUI
    public void init() {
                        setSize(300, 300);
                table = new Table(this);
                add(table);
                                setContentPane(table); // makes our graphical JPanel container the content pane for the Applet
                // createGUI(); // this has been moved onto the table class
            }

    public void stop() {

    }

}
```

And now the Table class:

```
import java.awt.*; // needed for old style graphics stuff
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*; // gives us swing stuff
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*; // useful for anything using URLs

public class Table extends JPanel {
// attributes go here
    Pinball pb;
    Color bgColour;
    JPanel eastPanel;
    JPanel logoPanel;
    JPanel livesPanel;
    JPanel scorePanel;
    JPanel tablePanel;
    JPanel scrollTextPanel;
        Image logo;

    // constructor goes here
public Table(Pinball pb) {
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    this.pb = pb;
    // this is not needed anymore, with the new loadImage class down the bottom
//  Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); // needed to get images
//  logo = tk.getImage(base + "images/logo.jpg");
        logo = loadImage("logo.jpg");
     createGUI();
        }

        // public methods go here
        // all GUI creation stuff goes here
        public void createGUI() {
            /* allows the three parts (top, middle and right) 
             * to be made through (north, center and right) */
                    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    // setting the background colour
                    bgColour = new Color(190, 186, 221); // makes the sky blue colour for the background.
                    setBackground(bgColour);
                                                        // now putting a panel for the east side
                    eastPanel = new JPanel();
                    eastPanel.setBackground(bgColour);
                    eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
                    eastPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 280));
                                    logoPanel = new JPanel();
    logoPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    logoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    logoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, Color.white));
    //JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Logos go here");
    //logoPanel.add(label1);
    eastPanel.add(logoPanel, "North");
    livesPanel = new JPanel();
    livesPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    livesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Lives go here");
    livesPanel.add(label2);
    eastPanel.add(livesPanel, "Center");
    scorePanel = new JPanel();
    scorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    scorePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Scores go here");
    scorePanel.add(label3);
    eastPanel.add(scorePanel, "South");
add(eastPanel, "East");
    tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.setBackground(bgColour);
    tablePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 280));
    add(tablePanel, "Center");
    scrollTextPanel = new JPanel();
    scrollTextPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
    scrollTextPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    scrollTextPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    add(scrollTextPanel, "North");
    // repaint();
                        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(logo, 5, 5, 90, 90, null);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300); // for testing, does not work
              }

        // a little useful method for handling loading of images and stuff
        public BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
               URL url = new URL(pb.getCodeBase(), "images/" + filename);
               image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    return image;
        }

}
```

Comment: Adding components in initialization to your JPanel subclass plus overriding paintComponent won't play nicely together.

Comment: @justkt: they can play nicely if the covering component's opaque property is set to false. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your Table JPanel is covered by other JPanels, which can be OK, but you won't be able to see through an opaque component that is covering it, in particular the tablePanel JPanel.  For example, try:

```
  tablePanel = new JPanel();
  // tablePanel.setBackground(bgColour); //!! removed
  tablePanel.setOpaque(false); //!! added
```

And see what happens.

An unrelated question for you regarding this code here:

```
   public void init() {
      setSize(300, 300);
      table = new Table(this);
      add(table);
      setContentPane(table); // makes our graphical JPanel container the content
```

Why are you adding the table Table object twice, once to the JApplet's contentPane and then next *as* the JApplet's contentPane?

Comment: I was *way* too slow on that one. ;)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the swift response. Unfortunately that didn't work ideally, but that's my falt. I moved it to show the logo at 5, 5, to see if it was my previous set of coordinates (from the logoPanel). I was using logoPanel.getX() + 5 and logoPanel.getY() + 5 to get the coordinates before and wasn't sure if that was why it wasn't showing. Your code did work, though. I'm beginning to wonder, for a graphical project like this would it be best to use all graphics and no components? This is my first trip into graphics side stuff.

Comment: Hi @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, thanks for your swift response. Your code did work, but I can't use it efficiently, that's my falt though. I intended to make the logo appear in the logoPanel, but I was using code I wasn't sure that worked so I tried debugging this problem by moving the image. The code I was using before for the positioning was (logo, logoPanel.getX() + 5, logoPanel.getY() + 5 ...) etc. Will that work? I can use absolute coords if needs be.

Comment: Sorry for the triple post, I haven't figured out how to delete comments.

Answer (score 1):

Run then examine this code & see if you can spot the source of the problem.

```
// <applet code='Pinball' width='300' height='300'></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*; // useful for the drawing side, also going to be a JApplet
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Pinball extends JApplet {
    // variables go here
    Table table;

    // further initialisation of the GUI
    public void init() {
        table = new Table(this);
        setContentPane(table); // makes our graphical JPanel container the content pane for the Applet
    }
}

class Table extends JPanel {
    // attributes go here
    Pinball pb;
    Color bgColour;
    JPanel eastPanel;
    JPanel logoPanel;
    JPanel livesPanel;
    JPanel scorePanel;
    JPanel tablePanel;
    JPanel scrollTextPanel;
    Image logo;

    // constructor goes here
    public Table(Pinball pb) {
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.pb = pb;
        // this is not needed anymore, with the new loadImage class down the bottom
        //Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); // needed to get images
        //logo = tk.getImage(base + "images/logo.jpg");
        int size = 100;
        logo = //loadImage("logo.jpg");
            new BufferedImage( size,size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = logo.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0,0,size,size);

        createGUI();
    }

    // public methods go here
    // all GUI creation stuff goes here
    public void createGUI() {
        /* allows the three parts (top, middle and right)
         * to be made through (north, center and right) */
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(20,20));
        // setting the background colour
        bgColour = new Color(190, 186, 221); // makes the sky blue colour for the background.
        setBackground(bgColour);
        // now putting a panel for the east side
        eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setBackground(bgColour);
        eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        eastPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 280));
        logoPanel = new JPanel();
        logoPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        logoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        logoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, Color.green));
        eastPanel.add(logoPanel, "North");
        livesPanel = new JPanel();
        livesPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        livesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Lives go here");
        livesPanel.add(label2);
        eastPanel.add(livesPanel, "Center");
        scorePanel = new JPanel();
        scorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scorePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Scores go here");
        scorePanel.add(label3);
        eastPanel.add(scorePanel, "South");
        add(eastPanel, "East");
        tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.setBackground(bgColour);
        tablePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 280));
        add(tablePanel, "Center");
        scrollTextPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollTextPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
        scrollTextPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollTextPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add(scrollTextPanel, "North");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paintComponent");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawImage(logo, 5, 5, 90, 90, this);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300); // for testing, does not work
    }

    // a little useful method for handling loading of images and stuff
    public BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(pb.getCodeBase(), "images/" + filename);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do NOT ignore exceptions in broken code.
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew Thompson, thanks for that. So are you saying you think/thought it was my loadImage method? I've tried a couple of permutations on it, but will try that one if you think it'll help.

Comment: No.  Remove the arguments of the 1st call to a `BorderLayout` constructor and check the difference.  It should make the partially shown image/line disappear again.  Just another aside.  I resisted changing most of the `setPreferredSize()` calls, but note that it is better to remove them and work out how to lay the GUI out properly.