# I am looking for a good example of adding an image to an applet

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to add an image to my applet. I have googled this but I have not found a decent example that I understand. Does anyone know where I can find a good example of adding an image to and applet?

I got this online but when I run the applet it doesn't display my image.

```
   public class Lab5 extends JApplet {
        //Lab5(){}


        Image img;

        public void init() {
                img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "img\flag0.gif");                 
        }


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, this);
        }
}
```

Below is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <applet code="Lab5.class" width= 250 height = 50></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many, many examples available as I'm sure you've seen. I'm not sure how we can point you to a "better" example or give you helpful advice unless you tell us which sites you've studied and what specifically about the current examples you don't understand, or what code isn't working for you and what errors you may be seeing. Consider putting more effort into this question if it is to have a hope of getting a decent answer.

Comment: First you'll want to read the tutorials on how to create applets. Consider putting the image into an ImageIcon and that into a JLabel. You can then give the JLabel a decent layout manager such as a BorderLayout, make it opaque and make it the contentPane for the applet. Alternatively you can draw the image in the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel and make it the contentPane for the applet.

Comment: Okay I will look at it again. I copied that almost verbatum out of my class book

Comment: Edited question: swing and image tags added. Let's try to attract some Swing experts here.

Comment: [Loading and Drawing an Image in an Applet](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.applet/LoadImageApplet.html)

Comment: @Max that is pretty much what I have above why doesn't my code show the image. Am I adding it to the HTML properly

Comment: @user512915: you're trying to draw it in a paintComponent method but applet doesn't even have a paintComponent method. Again, do the drawing in a JLabel or a JPanel and again add it to the applet's contentPane. Please look at my suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9342358/522444).

Comment: @user512915: Change paintComponent() to paint()

Comment: Also check out Andrew Thompson's recommendations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5744763/522444).

Comment: @Max: no, don't ever draw directly in a top-level window. Please don't give this advice.

Comment: I don't think I fully grasp how to use and Applet yet. I am doing more research on how they function.

Comment: @user512915 you may also want to consider using <object> tags instead of <applet>, as it's been depreciated.

Comment: @Hawken Thanks our book uses <applet>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example that shows an image from a URL from the internet. You'd probably use a resource in the internet url's place, such as an image held in a directory of the application's jar:

Class SimpleAppletImage.java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleAppletImage extends JApplet {
   @Override
   public void init() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               try {
                  // you might want to use a file in place of a URL here
                  URL url = new URL("http://duke.kenai.com/gun/Gun.jpg");
                  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
                  MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(img );
                  getContentPane().add(myPanel);
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         });
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

class MyPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private BufferedImage img;

   public MyPanel(BufferedImage img) {
      this.img = img;
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (img != null) {
         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this); // corrected
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: We haven't gotten to exception handling yet gonna take me a few mins to figure out this code.